# DELETE FROM table WHERE condition in other table is met

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL so I appreciate your help and ask your forgiveness if this is something simple, I couldn't find the answer that helped me in other related posts.

I have to tables `PRC_FIX` and `IM_ITEM`. They both have a column `ITEM_NO`. I would like to delete a line in `PRC_FIX` where `IM_ITEM.ITEM_VEND_NO` equals `TOYM`.

Do I need to do some sort of join? Thanks again for your help.

Edit: I do not need help setting up the cascading DELETE. I am asking how to DELETE a line from ONLY `PRC_FIX` when a matching line in `IM_ITEM` meet a specific condition.

Comment: The script in my answer deletes just `PRC_FIX` as you want. try it and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clever approach :

```
DELETE PRC_FIX
FROM PRC_FIX
INNER JOIN IM_ITEM ON IM_ITEM.ITEM_NO = PRC_FIX.ITEM_NO 
           AND IM_ITEM.ITEM_VEND_NO = 'TOYM'
```

I hope to be helpful for you :)

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thanks

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this is to set up a cascading delete foreign key constraint.

To begin, delete the ones that don't exist:

```
delete f from prc_fix f
    where not exists (select 1 from im_item i where i.item_no = f.item_no);
```

Then, to automatically delete rows when they are removed from `im_item`:

```
alter table prc_fix add constraint fk_prc_fix_item_no
    foreign key (im_item) references im_item(item_no) on delete cascade;
```

Comment: They are already set to delete from PRC_FIX when they are deleted from IM_ITEM. I am looking to delete ONLY from PRC_FIX when a certain criteria is met

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM PRC_FIX  
WHERE ITEM_NO=
(SELECT ITEM_NO FROM IM_ITEM WHERE ITEM_VEND_NO='TOYM')
```